# stopPropagation not working in this instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation, jquery-click-event

Okay so a simple thing that I don't know how to search for, wasn't able to get an answer anywhere...

Basically, I'm using XML to populate a list. What happens is when clicking on the first tier li, it adds all the different suburbs to the child ul. This generates then the structure below:

```
<li class="province-active" style="background-image: url(&quot;img/minus-icon-storefinder.png&quot;);">
  <p>Gauteng</p>
  <ul class="province-sub-menu">
    <li class="province-sub-nav-item" data-suburb="Strijdom Park">Strijdom Park,Randburg</li>
    <li class="province-sub-nav-item" data-suburb="Edenvale">Edenvale,Eastrand</li>
    <li class="province-sub-nav-item" data-suburb="Strubens Valley">Strubens Valley,Roodepoort</li>
    <li class="province-sub-nav-item" data-suburb="Centurion">Centurion,Pretoria</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Okay the problem is, using the JQuery below, it first triggers the click event for "province-sub-nav-item" and then triggers the click event for "province-active" (the parent li). This is the JS I'm using for the children li.

```
$(document).on("click", ".province-sub-nav-item", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $shop = $(this).attr("data-suburb");
    loadShop($shop);
});
```

And this is the function for the parent li.

```
$(".province-active").click(function(e) {
    $li = $(this);
    $province = $li.children("p").text();
    $(".store-locations").css("width", 375);    
    getMap($li, $province, 15); 
});
```

So basically, I just need to not fire the click event for "province-active" without firing the click event for "province-active" and stopPropagation(); isn't working.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have used used event delegation and bounded the handler to teh document object.

So when event bubbles up the `province-active` elements handler will be triggered before the document objects handler is triggered so your stop propagation does not have any effect.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Yw344/1) - see the order of logging in the console

One possible solution is to use event delegation for the `province-active` element also

```
$(document).on("click", ".province-active", function (e) {
    var $li = $(this);
    var $province = $li.children("p").text();
    $(".store-locations").css("width", 375);    
    getMap($li, $province, 15);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Yw344/) - see the order of logging in the console

Alternatively this works too:

```
$(".province-sub-menu").on("click", ".province-sub-nav-item", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $shop = $(this).attr("data-suburb");
    loadShop($shop);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Arun, that makes perfect sense. Sorry I realize now what a completely stupid question this was. It's difficult to find solutions if you don't know what things are called. I've edited your answer with the solution that ended up working for me - hope you don't mind. Thanks!